# No of transformation steps to qualize array

Tags: c#

Hi Can any one tell me how to solve this problem in C#.
I have an array consisting of N elements. elements in array can be positive and negative intgers.
if A=[11, 3, 7, 1]
i want to calculate minimum no of transformation steps required to make array elements equal.
each element in array can be incremented or decremented by 1.

Array A will need 5 transformation steps to get A =[6, 6, 6, 6]

In very transformation each element has to be incremented or decremented by 1.

```
[11, 3, 7, 1] (initial array)
[10, 4, 6, 2] (after step 1)
[9, 5, 7, 3] (after step 2)
[8, 6, 6, 4] (after step 3)
[7, 7, 5, 5] (after step 4)
[6, 6, 6, 6] (after step 5)
```

Some in some arrays it may not be possible.

for example it is not possible with [1,4,7] to equalise elements to one number. In Such cases it should return -1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By transformation step you mean incrementing / decrementing each element in the sequence if needed ?

Comment: @user873244 with all respect to all writers on this question, I suggest to you to add algorithm(s) tag, to get more suggetions on this. On simple small arrays Jon's solution could be even correct, but not very sure if it's MATEMATICALLY correct for all types of destributions.

Comment: @Tigran: The distribution is irrelevant - only the maximum and minimum are relevant. See my edited answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Well presumably you just:

- Find the maximum element
- Find the minimum element
- The number of steps required will be half the difference between the maximum and the minimum, rounding up

You'd find the mean of the maximum and minimum element, rounding either up or down - it won't affect the number of steps - and then on each transformation step, you'd adjust each array element towards that mean.

EDIT: It's hard to see how you could get more efficient than this. In each step, the maxmimum and minimum elements can't get more than 2 closer to each other (the maximum being reduced by one, the minimum being increased by one) so the number of steps is *at least* half the difference, rounding up. My solution also says *how* you get to that state in exactly half the difference, rounding up, so it's a concrete solution, with none better.

EDIT: Here's the code to perform the transformations. Not as efficient as it can be, but it works...

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] current = new[] { 1, 3, 9, 11, 5 };

        // Check all odd or all even    
        if (current.Select(x => x % 2).Distinct().Skip(1).Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No solution!");
            return;
        }

        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", current));
            current = Transform(current);
        }
    }

    static int[] Transform(int[] input)
    {
        // We could do the "mean" calculation just once,
        // but it doesn't really matter for the sake of
        // demonstration
        int max = input.Max();
        int min = input.Min();
        if (max == min)
        {
            // Done
            return null;
        }

        int mean = (max + min) / 2;
        return input.Select(x => x > mean ? x - 1 : x + 1)
                    .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would that still work if you had an array like {300, 1, 1, 1, 1}?

Comment: @StephenT: It would if I've understood the question correctly. I'm assuming that each "transformation step" can increment or decrement *every* element of the array (otherwise the example in the question doesn't work). For the example you give, you'd end up with every element at 150 or 151.

Comment: In very transformation each element has to be incremented or decremented by 1.

Comment: @user873244: Or left alone, presumably? Otherwise it could only ever work if everything started with the same parity.

Comment: In very transformation each element has to be incremented or decremented by 1.
[11, 3, 7, 1] (initial array)
[10, 4, 6, 2] (after step 1)
[9, 5, 7, 3] (after step 2)
[8, 6, 6, 4] (after step 3)
[7, 7, 5, 5] (after step 4)
[6, 6, 6, 6] (after step 5)

Comment: Some in some arrays it may not be possible.

for example it is not possible with [1,4,7]

Comment: @user873244: It would have helped if you'd said that to start with. Your question says that each element *can* be incremented or decremented by 1, not that it *must* be. Still, *if* there's an answer, this algorithm gives it.

Comment: please check i have added some more details in question

Comment: @user873244: Okay, well you can account for that easily enough - just check for parity to start with. I've given an example of that in the code in my answer.

Comment: What does the `Select().Distinct().Skip().Any()` do?

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: The Select is projecting the numbers to 0 for even and 1 for odd. The Distinct is finding just the distinct values in that projection (i.e. 0 and 1). Skip(1).Any() is seeing whether there's more than one entry in the sequence, i.e. if there are both odd and even elements.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

*edit* sorry, this:

```
public int[] Equalize(int[] arr)
{
        int min = int.MaxValue;
        int max = int.MinValue;
        int parity = arr[0] % 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] % 2 != parity) return null;
            if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
            if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
        }
        int diff = (max - min) / 2;            
        int midVal = diff + min;
        return arr.Select(i => midVal).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `ROUND_DOWN(SUM(each) / N)` works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 version of **Jon Skeet** [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6902540/3494522)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

         System.out.println(getTransformationCount(new int[] {1, 3, 9, 11, 5 }));

    }

    public static int getTransformationCount(int[] A) {

        int count = 0;
        A = Transform(A);

        if (IntStream.of(A).map(n -> n % 2).distinct().skip(1).count() > 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        while (A != null) {
            A = Transform(A);
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int[] Transform(int[] input) {

        int min = Arrays.stream(input).max().getAsInt();
        int max = Arrays.stream(input).min().getAsInt();
        if (max == min) {
            return null;
        }

        int mean = (max + min) / 2;

        return Arrays.stream(input).map((n) -> {
            if (n > mean)
                return n - 1;
            else
                return n + 1;

        }).toArray();
    }
```